# Easy way to emulate module lookup in python

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to write a small compatibility layer between 2 projects which implement very similar functionality (one is a fork of the other), so that I can use one version under the hood in some cases, and the other in the other cases.

I would like to emulate the module lookup that the packages each use, but then dispatch to the correct package under the hood, depending on what is configured / installed.

For example, these lines...

```py
import version1
from version1 import Foo
from version1.baz import Bar
version1.Qux

import version2
from version2 import Foo
from version2.baz import Bar
version2.Qux
```

... should essentially be achievable by my compatibility layer with:

```py
# After configuring to use version1
import compat
from compat import Foo
from compat.baz import Bar
compat.Qux

# After configuring to use version2
# NOTE: repetition is intentional
import compat
from compat import Foo  
from compat.baz import Bar
compat.Qux
```

Obviously, I'm leaving some stuff out, like the internals, for simplicity. Basically, I'm using composition under the hood to actually do the work. But what I don't know how to do is make the import functionality (specifically the dotted access and the `from x import y` syntax behave as it should.

The biggest constraint is that I would prefer to use only one module to achieve this. I really DON'T want to have a module for every module in `version1` and `version2`.

Anyway, after googling around, it looks like I could implement the desired functionality with a custom `Loader` and/or `Finder` class, from `importlib`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.SourceLoader. However, I'm wondering if there's a simpler way, possibly using `__spec__` or `__path__`, or clever mocking.

Thanks. I found the docs very dense on this subject, and other resources a bit sparse. I was hoping there might be a nice medium between a simple and a hacky solution.